# Strange segmentation default

Tags: c, pointers

The problem I want to solve is: Count the number of occurrences of key words in a C code. Here's the code:

> The problem is that I get a segmentation fault. In my code I mentioned where
>   is the problem. Can you, please, explain me why ?

*In header:*

```
struct Chei
{
    char *cuv;
    int contor;
};

typedef struct Chei chei;

int ReadCode(char *a[]);
void  determine(chei *Ch, char *temp, int size);
void Frequency(chei *Ch, int nr_lines, char *a[], int size);
```

*In main:*

```
    chei tab_chei[] = {{"while", 0},{"if", 0}, {"case", 0}, {"switch",  0}};
    int size = sizeof(tab_chei)/sizeof(tab_chei[0]);
    char *Code[MaxL];
    int nr_lines;


    nr_lines = ReadCode(Code);//number of lines of text

    Frequency(tab_chei, nr_lines, Code, size);
```

*In function file:*
*I think there is no problem with reading text (function ReadCode() -- here I allocated memory for each Code[i] using malloc). I used an array of pointers to char for this.*

```
// This functions determines if the word "temp" is a keyword, and increases
     //"contor" if it is.

void  determine(chei *Ch, char *temp, int size)
{
    int i;


    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if (!strcmp(Ch[i].cuv, temp))
        {
            Ch[i].contor++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Array "a" contains the text.

```
void Frequency(chei *Ch, int nr_lines, char *a[], int size)
{
    int i;
    char temp[MaxCh];
    char *token = 0;


        strcpy(temp, a[0]);//I put a[0] as a particular case
        token = strtok(temp, " ");
        determine(Ch, token, size);

        while (token != NULL)
        {

            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            determine(ch, token, size); //here is the problem.
//I observed that if I delete this line, there is no error
//but still it isn't what I want to get
        }

        for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            {
                printf("\n%-10s%-4d", Ch[i].cuv, Ch[i].contor);
            }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
token = strtok(NULL, " ");
determine(ch, token, size); //here is the problem.
```

You're not checking `token` before passing it to `determine()`. The `strcmp()` call is undefined behaviour when given a null pointer.

Comment: You see that if I put `puts(token)` in while loop, it works fine.

Comment: Do you have any idea why can this be happening ?

Comment: `strtok()` will return NULL when there are no more tokens, which will crash in `determine()`. `puts()` may be handling the NULL you're giving it.

Comment: Thank you, I think that's the solution. I will check now.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you did not allocate memory for each of the string the pointer will point to, `char *Code[MaxL];`.

you only allocated memory for the pointers, you need to do something like

```
Code[0] = calloc(0, 100);
```

.

Comment: Don't cast malloc/calloc results in C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: o, I did not know that the ReadCode() allocate memory for it. And thanks, Rost0031.